# insert multiple rows to database looping

Tags: c#

what is wrong with this code what i am actually to achieve is
insert rows to database clear the textbox value and enter another record..
  the problem is at first loop data will be added successfully...but on the next iteration loops it will add empty strings to the rows of database but what i want is accept input from textbox and continue iterating...please try to read the code and help me ...it is been 2 weeks since am trying so solve this ..
again what i want to do
     -user enter number of group members
     - the group members have column like ,first name,last name gender,city.etc
  FOR all the group members (eg:6 group membrs) add 6 rows of of different column will be added
but my code does is add the first rows and the rest 5 row's will be empty data 
Sorry for my bad english..somebody please try to think what i am thinking

```
    {{
        private void btnAddloan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    

            if (txtname.Text != "" && txtlname.Text != "")
            {
                int c=0;
                int input=int.Parse(txttotalnumberofgroupmembers.Text);

                do
                {
                    string connstr = "Data Source=GER-PC\\PLEASEGOD;Initial Catalog=ACSI;Integrated Security=True";
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);
                    con.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Customer(FirstName,LastName)  values(@n,@p)", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", txtname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtlname.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    lblnotify.Content = c + 1 + "" + "members added";
                     //clear textbox values and wait for another input
                    txtname.Text = "";
                    txtlname.Text = "";

                    if (txtname.Text != "" && txtlname.Text != "")
                   {
                      continue;

                   }
                  else
                   {

                        MessageBoxResult result =MessageBox.Show("procces","Continue Adding Memebers",MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                        //txtname.Text = s;
                        //txtlname.Text= s1;
                         //MessageBox.Show();
                        switch (result)
                        {
                            case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                                if (txtname.Text != "")
                                {

                                }
                                else
                                {


                                }
                                break;
                            case MessageBoxResult.No:
                                break;
                            case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                                break;

                        }

                   }
                   c++;
                } while (c < input);


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("plese fill first name and last name");

            }


                }
```

Comment: You have two text boxes.  You also have a text box that holds the total number of records you want to insert.  User clicks enters data in the textboxes, hits the button - you insert the data from the text boxes, and then clear the data.  After that, there's no more data to insert because your inputs have been cleared.  Either provide enough input boxes for the user to enter every record, or simply do one insert per group of data.

Comment: Seems like this is your first time with GUI/event driven programming. You are doing it wrong, Just add one record each time user clicks the button and then clear the form. Let the user type again and click the button to insert next record.

Comment: ok but i have to show how many group members added and how many remain

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing the **txtname.Text** and **txtlname.Text** value after you do the insert. In the next iteration you're recreating the Parameters, but this time your text values are EMPTY.

```
 txtname.Text = "";
 txtlname.Text = "";
```

Instead of recreating your command object, why not just execute the command object N times. Like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Customer(FirstName,LastName)  values(@n,@p)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtlname.Text);

for(int i = 0; i < input; i++)
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: thanks joshgo... k i will try both mentioned methods..i will post back my results

Comment: Note: This will just fix your current bug, and insert the same names N times. I know you really want to enter different user names. That will require more changes to your application like Tim and Matthew said above. Hopefully this will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: thanks a lot matthew and tim i finaly found a way to get what i want ..here is the code..ya i was just doing wrongly..i don't even need loops.. here is my coode

Comment: first I initialize int c at class level                     `try{sql staments,commands,parameters here }                 cathch{}                                                                  finally     { txtname.Text = "";
                     txtlname.Text = "";
                    
                     if (input== c )'
                     {
                         MessageBox.Show("Dude you finished inserting your members easily");
                         txttotalnumberofgroupmembers.Text = "";
                     }
                     c = c + 1;}`

Comment: Side note: when using c# and sql server, you can use a table valued parameter to insert multiple records with a single insert statement instead of insert each row individually.